# Azure Authorization Errror for Storage Account Creation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-identity

I m creating an API with Nodejs which creates Storage Account using Azure Identtiy and Arm-storage Sdk. The problem is that when ever I run the below code I get Authorization erorr which I cant seem to resolve. I have set all kinds of authorization but I keep getting this error on the Registered App in Azure AD.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK3w6.png)

Below is my code:

```
    const storageAccountName = params.CustomerID;
    const location =params.SelectedRegion;       

    // Initialize the Azure Storage Management client
    const credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential({
        managedIdentityClientId: process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        tenantId: process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID
    });        
    
    // const credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    const storageClient = new StorageManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);

    // Define the properties of the storage account
    const storageAccountParameters = {
        sku: {
            name: "Standard_LRS",
        },
        kind: "StorageV2",
        location: location,
        accessTier: "Hot",
    };
    
    try {
        // Create the storage account
        const operationResponse = await storageClient.storageAccounts.beginCreateAndWait(
            resourceGroupName,
            storageAccountName,
            storageAccountParameters
        );`
    }catch (err) {
        console.error("Error creating Storage Account:", err.message);
        throw new Error(`${err.message}`);
    }
```

I have tried giving permissions on App Registration and Azure Ad. But still the error persists. The account I m using has contributor role so that shouldn't be the problem. The problem is with the App registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error tells us that you don't have proper permission to create the storage account.

In the code, you need to use **`clientsecretcredential`** to create a storage account with a contributor role.

I have an app with name **`testvenkat`** which has **`contributor`** role  like below:

**Portal:**

[image]

Now, you can use the below code to create storage using app registration.

**Code:**

```
const {ClientSecretCredential} = require("@azure/identity");
const { StorageManagementClient } = require("@azure/arm-storage");


const  subscriptionId  =  "your-subscription-id";
const  resourceGroupName  =  "your-resource-group-name";
const storageAccountName = "venkat678";
const location = "East US";
const credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(
"your-tenant-id",
"your-client-id",
"your-client-secret"
);

const storageClient = new StorageManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);

const storageAccountParameters = {
    sku: {
        name: "Standard_LRS",
    },
    kind: "StorageV2",
    location: location,
    accessTier: "Hot",
};

try {
    const operationResponse = storageClient.storageAccounts.beginCreateAndWait(
        resourceGroupName,
        storageAccountName,
        storageAccountParameters
    );
    console.log("Storage account created successfully");
} catch (err) {
    console.error("Error creating storage account:", err.message);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Storage account created successfully
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Also, if you don't have contributor role to your app registration try to assign **`Storage account contributor role`**.

[image]